# C# - Safe a Base64 as Gif, when the webRequest sends XML?

Tags: c#, xml, image, base64, webrequest

I sended a WebRequest, and got as Response a String with XML Code within my content.

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("...");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(responseFromServer);

        Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        }

        image.Save("File", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
```

The Problem is that "Convert.FromBase64String(responseFromServer)" cant convert to base 64, because the response is:

```
       "<string xmlns="*LINK*"> 'content' </string>"
```

Can I remove these Tags, or copy out the content?

I hope you got my problem:) Thanks for help and sorry for the bad english x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using `XmlReader` for this.

```
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("...");
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
//StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
//string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

//byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(responseFromServer);

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(dataStream))
{
    reader.Read();
    reader.Read();
    string base64 = reader.Value;
    byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(base64);
    Image image;
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
    {
        image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        image.Save("File", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
    }
}
```

There is a method for converting from Base64 in the element value directly, but you'd need to know things that more or less require you to read your whole stream anyway to do that (you can look at the edit history to see me working through that ;).

Comment: No problem - if this answer helped you consider upvoting and marking as the correct answer for future readers.

Answer (score 2):

you can use XmlDocument..

```
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("...");
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(reader);
        byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(doc.GetElementsByTagName("string")[0].InnerText);

        System.Drawing.Image image;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
        }
```